# How do aqueous nanoparticle suspensions behave?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, biochemistry

I have found many pictures of nanoparticle suspensions on the web, but I can find no indication of how these suspensions behave, e.g. do the nanoparticles remain in suspension indefinitely, or do they precipitate out after a while, and if they precipitate out, how long does that take?

Regarding appearance, if one had a suspension of iron oxide nanoparticles in water at neutral pH and an iron concentration of about 20 micro moles per litre, could this give the water a uniform brown tint when viewed through 20cm of water?

I believe that I may have produced a suspension of iron oxide nanoparticles via biological means, which is why I have included the biochemistry tag.

Update:
I understand that nanoparticles are considered to exist in the size range 1nm to 100nm.  Perhaps particles as small as 1nm will be kept in suspension by Brownian motion, and perhaps larger particles will eventually settle to the bottom of the container, but I don't know, that's why I'm asking!

Comment: Before the buzzword nanoparticles came into being, this science was called colloidal chemistry. In other words, nanoparticles were colloid particles. See Faraday's work on colloids. Gold colloids are stable suspensions for years. All colloids are prone to settling. It is just a matter of time, some colloid may take years to settle.

Comment: @AChem        [Faraday’s colloidal gold](https://www.rigb.org/explore-science/explore/collection/michael-faradays-gold-colloids) is still unsettled after 150 years!

Comment: Note that even pollen particles in  micrometer range are visibly affected by Brownian motion, as that is how it was discovered. And the mass to be disturbed by random hits decreases with r^3.

Comment: Chances are that e.g. the *Journal of Chemical Education* holds a publication which can be both introduction into theory and application for a lab class ([2018JChemEduc121](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00277) as an example).  In addition, `nanoparticles` and `nanoparticle formation` are suggested keywords in ACS' search mask to cover all their journals after typing just a couple of characters. Not specific to NP of iron, but frequently posters mention sodium dodecylsulfate (SDS) as detergent added to keep suspended NPs separate from each other (again because of energies).

Comment: Thanks to all who responded, but particularly to AChem whose input I found the most helpful.